# How to retain certain file during uninstallation of a winform app?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I would like to retain certain file during uninstall because it contain some configuration info. I don't want to create the file again after I install next time.

Is there a way to do it? Can't seem to find any info regarding this online.

Comment: so you are installing it via .msi file? or how do you install and uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Windows Installer` project you can set `Permanent = True` of your object (right click on your object in your setup project > Properties).